# Ltspice could not open library file

Tags: ltspice

I tried to export sub and sym file on an other PC. I decided to copy the sub files that I created in the "LTspiceXVII\lib\sub" and past it into the same folder of the other PC. I did the same for the sym files. When I tried to simulate the same file which worked on the original PC, it does not work "Could not open library file". I do not want to redo all the files that I created... And actually I do not know why it would change. I will just redo the symbol file. It probably miss a link between the symbol file and the sub file ?

Have a nice day.

Comment: Open up one of the offending symbol files (their <filename>.asy file) with notepad. Look through it to find any system directories there. My guess is that you will find your reason. If not, then there are some other questions to ask you. But that one comes first in my mind.

Comment: YOU MAKE MY DAY ! Thank you ! :D

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that helped out!

Comment: @Jess That usually happens when using autogenerated symbols. I'm afraid it's a known gimmick, and the only way to correct it is, as jonk said, to manually edit the `.asy` file. Or take 1 extra minute to make your own symbol (without maming the same mistake).

Comment: Thank you !!! You re saying that I should save at an other place than at the "autogenerated" folder ? It is possible that I took my symbols into this folder and then cut/paste it in an other folder.